# Eclipse: Show XQDT output in Eclipse's graphical XML editor?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xquery

I'm using the XQDT (XQuery Development Tools) plugin for Eclipse, and I'd like to view query results in Eclipse's graphical XML editor rather than in the console. Does anyone know of a way to redirect output in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

1. create a empty XML file anywhere in the workspace or file system;
2. Open Menu "Run" -> "Run configuration...";
3. select an existing XQuery Run config or create a new one;
4. In the right part of the window (run config details), select "common";
5. At "Standard Input and Output", check "File:"
6. select the empty xml file created in step one, using the button "Workspace" or "file system";
7. Push "Close", or "Run" if you want to start the xquery immediately.

That's it - eclipse will write the XQuery output directly into the XML file. Just open the file after the XQuery run has finished.